# Android Studio Java equivalent of C# .Net WinForms DataGridView Object List DataSource

Tags: java, android-studio, datagridview

I'm looking for a simple way to get a gridview with sortable headers (with captions) in Android Studio using Java. You know, like those in Visual Studio C# .Net, where you create a class, a List, you give the list to the gridview as a DataSource... nothing more verbose than this, something very simple to understand and clear to read, for people coming from VS.

Thanks for your precious time!
M

This is the equivalent in VS2010 C# WinForms:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Worker> workers = new List<Worker>();

            #region Fill the list
            Worker w1 = new Worker();
            w1.Id = 1;
            w1.Nome = "Mike";
            w1.Dob = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01);

            workers.Add(w1);

            Worker w2 = new Worker();
            w2.Id = 1;
            w2.Nome = "Jade";
            w2.Dob = new DateTime(2002, 02, 02);

            workers.Add(w2);
            #endregion

            dataGridView1.DataSource = workers.ToList();
        }
    }

    public class Worker
    {
        private int _id;

        public int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        private string _nome;

        public string Nome
        {
            get { return _nome; }
            set { _nome = value; }
        }

        private DateTime _dob;

        public DateTime Dob
        {
            get { return _dob; }
            set { _dob = value; }
        }
    }


}
```

This is the result:
[image]

I don't have idea, the know-how, everything I've seen I understand it's not what I want, and I think it should be something easy to write, it's not a flying shuttle.

Comment: With “sortable” I mean the capability, for next implementations.

Comment: Both ids are wrongly set to 1, obv I mean 1, 2…